# named chunk on asynchronous module loading

Tags: webpack

If you have an entry `main.js` with this kind of content :

```
require.ensure('a', function(module){
    //
}, 'chunk1');

require.ensure('b', function(module){
    //
}, 'chunk1');

require.ensure('c', function(module){
    //
}, 'chunk2');

require.ensure('c', function(module){
    //
}, 'chunk2');
```

Webpack will output 3 files : `main.js`, `chunk1.js` and `chunk2.js` where chunk1 is composed of modules a and b and chunk2 is composed of modules c and d;

Now I'm trying to get the same behavior using *dynamic asynchronous require* like that :

```
function dynamicLoad(letter){
    require(['./modules/' + letter + '.js'], function(module){
        //
    });
}
```

Here we are not telling webpack how to merge modules together so the outputs will be : `main.js` and `1.1.js` where 1.1 is composed of all modules a, b, c and d.

Is there a way to define how we want (or prefer) modules to be merged into chunks ?

UPDATE :

I found this plugin [split-by-name-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/soundcloud/split-by-name-webpack-plugin) which does exactly what I want but just for chunk entry, does not work for dynamic chunk.
I'll look into this plugin and see if I can make it to work as I want.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because all dynamic expression like `require(['./modules/' + letter + '.js']` are really [not so dynamic](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html#dynamic-require-rewriting) and webpack resolves them in the build step. So internally it rewrites your require into `require.context`, searches the directory for all files that will suffice (effectively all js files in the `modules` dir) and bundle them into one file.

To force webpack to create a separate bundle for the every file you need to use `require.ensure`. But wrapping every file into it is a very tedious process, so I believe you're looking for the [bundle loader](https://github.com/webpack/bundle-loader). It will do this for you automatically.

Comment: How do you arbitrarily group some modules together then ? I've been able to make it work using ```require.include()``` but I have to do it on all the modules I want to bundle together. Is there a better solution ?

Comment: You still can pass the `name` parameter to the loader to control in what chunk what module goes + all the dependencies of the module will be bundled automatically. If this is still not what you want for some reason, can you please provide more info about what you want to achieve?